# Other than stabbing it with an enchanted, 1000-year-old, goblin-made sword, how else can I kill a Basilisk?

Tags: harry-potter, basilisk

So today I found out that my best friend's sister got taken by a beast into a place called the Chamber of Secretions.

I went down there together with my best friend Wazlib to try and rescue her using only two magical wooden sticks (one was broken) and a hysterical teacher.
Unfortunately along the way I get separated from them and I'm left with only one wand. Anyways, it gets stolen by a memory-ghost later on and I couldn't be bothered to wrest it back just yet.

No phoenix arrives to save the day. No magical hat containing a sword appears.

#### **Is there another sure-fire way to kill a Basilisk other than using the Sword of Gryffindor (and the help of a phoenix)?**

If they're similar to snakes, could I just conjure a few giant mongooses to help me kill it, or alternatively Avada it to death? Does Rowling answer this?

---

<sub>For those with a low sense of humour... read on</sub>

> So, I was wondering if the Basilisk in the Chamber of Secrets had any other weaknesses other than having to be stabbed by the Sword of Gryffindor. I think it's a bit ridiculous that Harry and **Ronald** decide to just waltz into the Chamber armed with only two wands, trying to save Ginny from the "likely" Basilisk in there. 
>  **If Fawkes didn't come, how else could the Basilisk have been killed?**

Comment: No. You don't have a wand.

Comment: I bet smashing its head with a giant rock would help.

Comment: Showing it its own reflection in a mirror [may do it](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97623/will-a-basilisk-get-petrified-if-it-sees-itself-in-mirror).

Comment: If you turn a [time-turner](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Time-Turner) enough times, you can stomp the basilisk's egg before it hatches. It's sure-fire as long as there is [no paradox-preventing principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novikov_self-consistency_principle) in action in your Universe, so your mileage may vary ...

Comment: I don't see why the basilisk wouldn't be killable via any ordinary killing method. Granted, it's a huge, super-powerful snake, with certain powers, but ultimately, it's just another creature with it's own strengths and weaknesses. There only reason why a basilisk wouldn't be killable by pummeling it with your bare hands is the same reason a person probably wouldn't be too successful taking down a grizzly with his bear hands. It's simply a huge beast.

Comment: Related: [Can a fake rooster kill a Basilisk?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/162086/31394)

Comment: what's with the unnecessary obfuscation of names and such?. The actual question references the sword of Gryffindor properly, so I don't get the whole "wazlib" and "secretions" bit. I'd like the content of the question put right or the purpose of the oddity explained. Imo it serves no purpose and is unhelpful to the otherwise interesting question

Comment: Conjure up atom bomb?

Comment: @xDaizu - They only go back a maximum of five hours according to Rowlingcanon.

Comment: @Salmononius2, in fact one might wonder whether *bear* hands would be particularly *effective* at taking down a grizzly.  :-)

Comment: +1 for Ronil Wazlib. Love that bloke.

Comment: Simple, A giant blind mangoose that know kung-fu. This would have made a great fight.

Comment: @NKCampbell you raise a good point! See the spoiler quote I've just added in. :-)

Comment: Wow... you look very calm, considering you are in front of a giant serpent-like monster which can kill you in a lot of different painful ways..

Comment: And here I was thinking that the plural of "mongoose" is "mongeese"...

Comment: @M.Herzkamp It should be.

Comment: @M.Herzkamp I thought about that while writing my question, but then I did a quick Google search and clicked on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongoose): `The form of the English name (since 1698) was altered to its "-goose" ending by folk-etymology. It has no etymological connection with the word goose. Historically, it has also been spelled "mungoose". The plural form is mongooses, or, rarely, mongeese.`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

From Chamber of Secrets (emphasis mine):

> It was a page torn from a very old library book [...] 
>   *Spiders flee before the Basilisk, for it is their mortal enemy, and the 
>   **Basilisk flees only from the crowing of the rooster, which is fatal to it**.*

So, the Basilisk has no natural enemies other than the rooster (so the mongooses won't be any good). I don't think something like Avada Kedavra would be enough to kill it though, but I can't remember any reference in the books.

Comment: the Basilisk has no *natural* enemies: the giant mongooses as asked in the question wouldn't be natural enemies

Comment: A trick could work to disable the basilisk for a while and release the prisoner. A number of such tricks were employed by Harry to beat large creatures, for example: outflying the dragon in GoF, smashing a club on troll's head in PS, etc. The trouble with Harry in CoS was that he did not know a lot of spells an adult wizard could.

Comment: I wonder if Fiendfyre could help...

Comment: @user13267 well, natural in the Harry Potter universe. I *assume* that if giant <insert animal here> was a way to kill a basilisk, the book from the library would say so.

Comment: @elrond a book from the library might not list an animal that is specifically conjured for the task (take a narural mongoose and enlarge it until it is a match for the Basilisk). Or a giant rooster?

Comment: Why wouldn't Avada Kedavra work? It can kill any living creature. And the basilisk is surely a living creature. The fact that Harry was so famous for being the only one who ever survived it, makes it even more clear. Otherwise, Harry would be just another random lucky survivor among lots of others.

Comment: @vsz It just seems to me that it wouldn't be such a terrifying monster if it could be killed by a curse that any trained wizard can do. Plus, Harry is the only *human* that survived the killing curse, I'm not sure that applies to any living creature (for example giants are known to be resistant to attacks).

Comment: JKR didn't think this entirely through. If the crowing of the rooster is fatal to the Basilisk, then the Basilisk can't flee it; It should croak on the spot or nearly. Aside from that, if a rooster engages in a staring contest with a Basilisk... who wins?

Comment: @elrond : it's such a terrifying monster because it kills you with its gaze before you can point your wand at it. By the way, to be able to aim at it, you have to look at it. And then you are dead.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60847/discussion-on-answer-by-elrond-other-than-stabbing-it-with-an-enchanted-1000-ye).

Comment: The killing curse won't work, but roosters do!

Comment: The Killing Curse would probably work on the Basalisk, but like Moody Crouch says, it takes a lot of power behind it to kill even a person with it. What sort of power that is, we don't really get to see, but I think it's assumed that a powerful enough magic-user could kill *anything* with a Killing Curse.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Well, the author of the book she created didn't think it through. I'm an antique dealer - I've got some books that are full of terrible advice and not thought through. One of the medical books from the 1800s says women shouldn't drink when they're pregnant (awesome!) because they could stumble and fall which would hurt the baby (wait... technically true, I guess...?)

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist JKR lifted that entirely from the original legends, and indeed in the real world travellers would bring roosters with them journeying through parts of Cantabria that were said to be were basilisks lived. Its' not unreasonable to imagine that a sonar weapon could be fatal at close range and painful or merely scary further away. So fleeing a rooster's crowing would be akin to how most animals will flee a fire, which is likewise fatal to them.

Comment: @elrond - What's the point of being a trained wizard if your powers don't include the ability to kill terrifying monsters with a well-placed spell or two?  Surely magic wouldn't be a big deal if it was only good for parlor tricks.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Besides what Jon Hanna says (quite true I might add; it's what I thought of immediately) who is to say the rooster is crowing non-stop? Since they don't it's easy enough to flee when it sees them. And just because it sees the rooster doesn't mean the rooster sees it directly thus somehow killing it (as for turning to stone I don't know the full story there but I don't think it really matters).

Answer (score 14):

While the crow of a rooster is a sure-fire way to kill a Basilisk, there is no sense in the books that Basilisks have any special defenses.

After all, Fawkes was able to poke out its eyes, which at least suggests that it would be susceptible to the Conjunctivitis Curse. Though, "susceptible" might be a little strong, since you usually need to be looking at the target of a curse, and that's probably not the best play when taking on a creature that kills you if you see its eyes.

It is also not stated that Basilisks have any special magical defenses the way Giants and Dragons mostly do. After all, most curses involve looking at the target, so the Basilisk's death glare would seem sufficient defense against them.

Given the lack of details, I would say that it's perfectly reasonable to assume that a Basilisk is a very dangerous and large snake. And thus, outside of rooster crowing, they would tend to be vulnerable to things that large snakes are vulnerable to: crushing, chopping, etc. I rather suspect that a sword would not need to be made of Goblin silver to be capable of cutting the head off of a Basilisk.

Though the sword probably wouldn't survive, due to the incredibly destructive Basilisk venom. But it might last long enough to do the job. Though this would involve getting within fang-range of the Basilisk, which also is quite fatal unless Phoenix tears are handy.

Mongooses would likely not be helpful because Basilisks can kill with a look. Also, Basilisks are quite large, and the mongoose is not.

The big problem here is that you posed this as a *wand-less* fight. That tends to narrow down ones Wizarding options pretty drastically. So unless there were weapons lying around, or one could lure the Basilisk into some kind of trap (and do so while effectively blind), this encounter will probably not end well. While the Basilisk would likely be injured by hurled rocks, hitting targets while blind is quite hard.

Comment: RPG. Why waste time with magic when you have perfectly suited mundane tools at your disposal?

Answer (score 4):

Possibly a mirror.

Certainly in the legends about basilisks (and likewise the similar cockatrice, who is also killed by rooster crows and may be a variant on the same original myth), it was often held that basilisks were not immune to their own petrifying gaze, and therefore a direct stare at a mirror would cause it to suffer the same fate as its victims.

One way that Rowling differs from that legend (and of course, like all legends there are variations so there's no "real" version), is that mirrors weaken the force of the attack. That does not mean that it is immune to that weakened attack, so potentially you could use a mirror to put one into a magical coma, and then while it was safely in that state just cut it into nice manageable chunks.

This isn't confirmed or denied canonically, so since Rowling says conventional armies would defeat wizards in a fight, which presumably includes whatever creatures they could recruit to fight with them, I'd recommend a large-caliber machine-gun fired at long-range, or maybe a few grenades.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there are a few ways (definitely not foolproof) I can think of:

1. Thanks to the memory ghost guy, you can talk to snakes. And if you have a good sense of humour, you can crack one or two great rooster jokes and let him DIE laughing.
2. As the dark lord suggested in comments as well, if you know swimming, jump into water. The basilisk will follow suit and if he sees his own eyes in the reflection, he'll die.
3. As you can talk to snakes, tell him that we are living in 21st century and slavery is over and the heir is making him a fool by letting him follow thousand years old practice (slavery), he might spare you and beat the crap out of the Slytherin heir.
4. As its almost 2 years since you have joined school now and there's quite some chance that you have interacted with Cedric Diggory. If he might have told you about Twilight, you can tell the full Twilight story to basilisk. He will automatically die of boredom.

P.S. : Please ignore if you find it odd that I'm using he/him rather than it for Basilisk. I am from India. We don't write animals/birds as non-livings.

Comment: The reflection would likely only cause it to petrify itself rather than kill it.  Sure that opens other options open which may then help cause its death, but a reflection may not be a surefire way of killing it.

Comment: another way: by snatching the wand from Riddle's memory ghost and then threatening to destroy the diary by Confringo or any other spell, so that Riddle tells a way to kill the beast. Riddle was fully capable of destroying the beast. As a last resort, as the snake listened to Riddle, Riddle could ask the Snake to suicide.

Comment: You could also tell the monster it isn't good enough and play the long game of ruining its self esteem and depriving it of the will to live.

Comment: @JackBNimble 
https://xkcd.com/1027/